# Tricky Regular Expression

Tags: c#, regex, repeat

I need to allow only alphanumeric characters (with uppercase) from 0-25 chars length and no lazy all-repetition numeric value.

I've got the first part:  Regex.IsMatch(tmpResult, "^[0-9A-Z]{0,25}$"); (that's easy)

111112 - match 
AABD333434 - match
55555555 - no match
555 - no match

Could anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
^(?!(.)\1*$)[0-9A-Z]{0,25}$
```

The extra `(?!(.)\1*$)` will reject any strings that is composed of repeating same character.

The `(?!…)` is a *negative lookahead* that will cause the primary regex fail if the `…` is matched, and the `(.)\1*` will match a string of repeating characters.

Answer (score 0):

You could just do it using a normal method... Once you have it match your first expression there, just use a subroutine to iterate through each character and return true the first time you encounter a character that differs from the first in the string.

It should return true after checking only the first 2 characters for *most* strings, unless it's an invalid string.

This should be equally as fast as a regex if not faster, if it is well implemented.